# How to delete entries from search box history in Mac Firefox

Tags: macos, mac, firefox

Is there any way to delete entries from the search box in the Mac version of Firefox? Not the suggestions, but the previous searches that come up automatically when I type into it. I am not trying to clear the whole history. I just want to delete individual items.

I noticed that in the Windows version, I can either select the items with the keyboard or hover over them with the mouse, then press my Delete key, and they get deleted. In the Mac version, this doesn't work. I tried many other combinations such as Shift+Delete, Ctrl+Delete, Option+Delete, Cmd+Delete, Fn+Delete, Fn+Cmd+Delete, Fn+Ctrl+Delete, and Fn+Option+Delete, with no luck.

Does anyone know if this can be done, and how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shift-Delete is the key combination to do this, however it's not the "delete" key you'll find on a macbook keyboard. On a MacBook or other Apple keyboard, you should use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

On a windows keyboard, the key in the top right corner of the main part of the keyboard (two rows above the enter/return key) is labeled "Backspace". There's a separate key labeled "Delete" to the right of that, grouped with Page Up/PageDown, Home and End. If you have an external keyboard with this layout, use that "Delete" key with Shift.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click in the Search box brings up a menu with "Clear Search History" in Firefox 3.5.3 on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I like this addon, which gives quick and easy access to the Clear Private Data functionality...

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1280