# how to prevent remove omnibox autocomplete entries, macos 10.8.4, chrome 28.0.1500.95

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete

If I type the letter Y in the omnibox, the whole URL is autocompleted to:

`youtube.com/player_api`

pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> does nothing, nor does <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>. (I have a Mac Air 2011, it has a key marked `delete` which is next to plus, and also has a `fn` key. The [verious](https://superuser.com/questions/175250/how-to-remove-one-or-all-auto-complete-text-entries-in-chrome) [suggestions](https://superuser.com/questions/567372/how-to-remove-all-autocomplete-urls-with-a-certain-url-in-chrome) for [getting](https://superuser.com/questions/171198/remove-auto-complete-field-entries-in-google-chrome) [rid](https://superuser.com/questions/60961/how-to-delete-entries-from-search-box-history-in-mac-firefox) of these entries *do not work* **for me**.

To get to YouTube homepage, I have to then CLICK in the omnibox (or press <kbd>→</kbd>, then <kbd>Backspace</kbd> over `/player_api` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If I touch any other key, it autocompletes again and puts `/player_api` back onto the url! ARGH!

I do not want to ever go to /player_api, and it's stupid that this is unremovable. It is particularly annoying for IP addresses, where if I type a number it autocompletes to any number of IP based addresses I've entered, and I can't get rid of the damned things because <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> no longer works.

To search for something beginning with Y (like YUI) I can just keep typing my word, as normal.

I DO want to search from the omnibox, I am signed into chrome and do use the multi-computer feature a LOT. I just don't want inline autocomplete.

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question. Do you want to disable autocomplete altogether? Or remove some URLs? Or prevent yourself from removing URLs altogether?

Comment: I want autocomplete to be disabled, which is the process where the box is filled in automatically to the right of what you type. i want to keep the drop down list of auto suggest options under the omnibox. I want to be able to search from the omnibox.

Comment: Shift-delete works fine for me, however the result isn't instant, you'll have to search for Y Again.

Answer (score 0):

May be this link [Google chrome instant](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/177873?hl=en&ref_topic=14676) will be help as far as I understood the problem. Its Google chromes feature to guess the URL, you can try pressing ESC key, if you don't want to select the guessed URL.

Comment: pressing `esc` blanks the entire url... So if I type in `you` then it autosuggests `youtube.com/player_api`; pressing `esc` then removes the whole url, including what I typed. `instant` is disabled already, but it still behaves like it is on.

Comment: Try using <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> after typing `you`, I hope it will solve your requirement.

Comment: is `backspace` the key that has `delete` written on it which is to the left of `end` and below `fn`, or the key that has `delete` written on it which is next to `+` and above `\` ? Damned apple keyboards!